# Template does not find form data from view

Tags: html, django, forms

I've read the django tutorial as well as tried numerous different ways of handling a form in django but it doesnt seem to work as expected. I have done significant research and reading including search google and stackoverflow but i cant seem to get it to work, maybe im not as sharp as the rest of you so thats why im asking you.

I'm creating a form to handle some data, then when the user clicks on the button i want want a new page to display the information that is about to be saved. After the user has clicked the button i get the template up but at the title and description fields there are no values present.

To describe a little more detailed:
1. I'm entering url /register/user/new which displays the form if there has not been any POST data sent
2. The form is filled out and the user clicks the button, the view validates the data and sends the user to /register/user/success which is handled by a different view. This view loads the template that is suppose to show the user the data the user has entered in to be sure it is correct.

I think the data is getting lost between the two views but if im using only one view and try to render another template when POST data is present i still only see the form so that doesnt work either. I have also tried using the args and kwargs parameters to the render function without any luck.

This is the view code for the first view:

```
def newUser(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data['username']
            description = form.cleaned_data['position']
            category = form.cleaned_data['department']
                # this is the first thing i tried, since the documentation states that you should always send a httpresponseredirect to avoid the user clicing twice on the form
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/register/user/success")

                # this is another attempt i used but it just displays the same form
                render(request, "registration_submitted.html", {'username': 'username'})
    else:
            form = NewUserForm()

def newUserSuccess(request):
    render_to_respone("newuser_submitted.html")
```

The template code is very simple, im just trying to print out a variable using the double curl braces like so: {{ username }} which outputs nothing.

This is the template code:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Story successfully submitted</title>
    <script src="{% static 'js/transition.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/collapse.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/footer.css' %}" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/custom.css' %}" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<p>The following information has been saved, please review:</p>
<ul>
    <li>Username: <b>{{ username }}</b> </li>
    <li>Position: <b>{{ position }}</b> </li>
    <li>Department: <b>{{ department }}</b> </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Update:
After clicking the submit button im being sent to the correct template page but when trying to write the values of the variables im just getting empty values. When debugging with firebug i see that the POST data is in fact being sent to the template:
Form data:
title:Testing
description:testing

But when writing {{ username }} im not getting the output. In the html template for the form i use the following:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
</div>
```

It should be working to use a simple template variable but it doesnt work.

Comment: You are not very clear, there is a form wizard in Django which can do what you are requesting, but it doesn't make much sense, submitting 2 times the same form is actually not a usual approach with posting data, there is validation inside which makes what you are trying to do in a better way, if the user is not sure about his submission Validation should handle the logic.
If on the other hand you do require a steeped form submission, then use the Form Wizard:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/

Comment: I've read about ModelForm and the Form class but i dont want to use them, at least not before i know how to handle forms properly in django without using them. I'm just trying to handle a form in django and apparently im doing it wrong so im asking you have i should do it in the best way without Form or ModelForm (please dont get into the discussion of why)

Comment: But you are already using a Form, what do you mean you don't want to use a Form Class? what is NewUserForm() then?

Comment: Spoke too soon, sorry about that, im of course like you say using the Form class

Comment: I edited the answer bellow (added some comments regarding the Post data between views).
If you actually want to display the newly created object, then as I mentioned you only need to use the CreateView, add a model attribute (as described in the Docs or in the link I posted) and when your form is saved the user will be displayed with the View of the specified object (unless you override the success url with something different)

Comment: Well i have read the django docs about Forms and other ways to create forms and i havent seen any examples or information about using it like this so i dont understand much of it and i dont see why i would do all that just to fetch values from a form and display them on a page..

Comment: Ehm, what you posted in your revision is excactly what CreateView does, you can always read the details in the Documentation and understand the logic.
Secondly you mention second form as a confirmation, but actually you are using it only to display the data that has been saved (although your code is missing the save function, (form.save()), thirdly all of the above is just 4 lines of code in a CreateView...

Comment: thanks for your time replying. Ah, i read a lot of django documentation a while ago and i now remember the view classes you are mentioning. Im not using them right now because im trying to be comfortable with the view functions first, and i had actually forgotten about the view classes but will will refresh on that after im more comfortable with the functions. I now have a single view function which is rendering a different template if POST data has been sent but when im trying to print the variables from the from i get empty data..

Comment: To add to my last reply i updated my first post

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45650/discussion-between-user2959896-and-petkostas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop and think through what is (not) happening here:

```
        title = form.cleaned_data['username']
        description = form.cleaned_data['position']
        category = form.cleaned_data['department']
            # this is the first thing i tried, since the documentation states that you should always send a httpresponseredirect to avoid the user clicing twice on the form
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/register/user/success")
```

You are setting some local variables in one view function, then redirecting to another view. It has no way to know about the local variables in your first view.

Some ways to pass info between views:

- via segments in the url you redirect to, defined in your urls.py in the regex url pattern,  which end up as args/kwargs to your second view, eg `/register/user/3` the `3` can be passed as an arg to the view function
- via the querystring of the url you redirect to, which will end up as keys in `request.GET` dict in your second view, eg `/register/user/success?title=whatever` ...not usually recommended in this kind of situation because it's easy to pass fake data via the url
- save to the session dict, `request.session['title'] = "whatever"` and access that in your second view... you could do, but if you already saved the user to the db why save the data again into the session ([which by default saves data to the db too](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/))

I'm assuming your `NewUserForm` is a ModelForm for the `User` model. In that case what you probably want to do is save the user to the database and redirect to a url containing the unique id of the newly saved user, so the second view can load that user back from the database:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, get_object_or_404

def new_user(request):
    form = NewUserForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        # note use of named view, not a url:
        return redirect('success_view', user_id=user.pk)
    return render(request, "new_user.html", {'form': form})

def success(request, user_id):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
    return render(request, "success.html", {'user': user})
```

and in your urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^register/user/$',
        view="myapp.views.new_user",
        name="new_user"),
    url(r'^register/user/success/(?P<user_id>\d+)?',
        view="myapp.views.success",
        name="success_view"),
)
```

As @petkostas points out, you can use Django's ready-made `CreateView` class to get all this functionality with just three lines of code, and that is to be recommended. On the other hand I think it is useful for you to see the equivalent in a basic hand-written view function to understand how these things work in Django.

Comment: Interesting comments and thanks for your time replying. Yes the CreateView class would probably be the prefered way but im not there yet, im like you say using hand-written view functions to understand what im doing, thats the only reason im using it right now, i had actually forgot about the view classes so i will take a look a that after im more comfortable with the view functions.

Comment: If i only have one view function like written in my first post and i render a new template if the view sees that POST data has been sent i get the new template but when i try to print out the variable names from the form i just get empty values, any ideas on that ?

Comment: maybe follow through the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) to get a feel for how views and templates work

Comment: To be able to use variables in your template you have to pass them in from the view that renders it, via the context dictionary... in your original code you tried this: `render(request, "registration_submitted.html", {'username': 'username'})` <- the context dictionary is that last part `{'username': 'username'}`, so in the template the only var you would have available is `username`

Comment: ...for it to actually do what you want though, that line of code above is not quite right (maybe copy & paste error), you need to _return_ the result of `render` and put the _variable_ `username` (not the string `'username'`) into the context: `return render(request, "registration_submitted.html", {'username': username})`

Answer (score 0):

Django uses Class Based Views nowdays to handle data for specific scenarios and it is the preffered way to work, in your case a CreateView Class would save you quite a few lines of code:

```
class NewUserCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = NewUserForm
    template_name = "yourformtemplate.html"
    success_url = yoursuccessurl
```

If you need to add additional logic in it, you can override the default methods, or even use them and add additional functionality / checks:
http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.6/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/

Your example does not actually require a double form submission, because you are only trying to revalidate data user submits, this data can be validated as normal process inside your form, you can even add checks in the view instead the form by overriding the post method:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Handles POST requests, instantiating a form instance with the passed
    POST variables and then checked for validity.
    """
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    if form.is_valid():
        """
        Form validation has passed, you can
        add inside here some additional checks
        """
        return self.form_valid(form)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```

any case this behavior is also available build in Django, it is named Form Wizard:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/

Remember that you can't pass POST data between posts, that's the reason you are not seeing what the user submitted in the redirect view, in case you want to add that second rendering of the form, you either have to create a rendered display of the form inside the form.is_valid() condition then re-post the data to another view (step2) and do the final validation before inserting data into your DB.
Form Wizard does that, in terms of temporarily storing data between redirections.

Comment: I don't think anything in the question suggests a Form Wizard is required

Comment: The question has been revised many times, you can check the edits and you shall see why my answer was pointing to the form wizard.
His initial question had the form of collecting post data and re submitting through a confirmation form, but it all got lost in translation as he actually wants what CreateView does, collect, store and render the stored object to the user.

Comment: Additionally if he indeed **does not want** to save the data in the db during the intial submission then the best method would be to implement a Form Wizard which temporarily saves the data between requests and allows the user to handle multiple forms before finalizing data submission.

Comment: yes, though the current version of the question does not look like that at all

Answer (score -1):

Try this as return of your function:

```
return render(request, "registration_submitted.html", {'username': title})
```

Comment: With your code which i tried before but didnt work im not getting directed to the submitted template which is correct but im still not getting any output when im trying to write the value of the variable with {{ username }}